# Почему я не могу снять лок

Tags: java, многопоточность, блокировки

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Votemap {
    private final ReentrantLock lock;
    Votemap (){
        lock = new ReentrantLock();
        lock.lock();
    }

    public void lockTest(){
        lock.unlock();
        System.out.println("баян");
    }
}
```

начинаем тестировать

```
import org.junit.Test;


public class VotemapTest {
private static class VotemapUnlocker extends Thread{
    private final Votemap votemap;
    VotemapUnlocker(Votemap votemap) {
        this.votemap = votemap;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.votemap.lockTest();
    }
}
    @Test
    public void lockTest() {
    Votemap votemap = new Votemap();
    VotemapUnlocker thread = new VotemapUnlocker(votemap);
    thread.start();
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

почему я не могу снять лок?  вылетает исключение

Comment: И какое же исключение? Дополните вопрос

Comment: IllegalMonitorStateException

Answer (score 4):

Потому что вы устанавливаете lock в одном потоке, а освободить его хотите в другом. ReentrantLock реализован так, что он должен освобождаться в том же потоке, в котором был захвачен.

Из [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#unlock--):

> public void unlock()
>
> Attempts to release this lock.
>
> If the current thread is the holder of this lock then the hold count
>   is decremented. If the hold count is now zero then the lock is
>   released. If the current thread is not the holder of this lock then
>   IllegalMonitorStateException is thrown.

Comment: спасибо понял разобрался

Comment: @AlexMur [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).